# Conditional CSS stop loading content

Tags: php, html, css, conditional-statements

OK, I'm new to this so bear with me. I have my website which is set up for Internet Explorer 9 and Safari, Chrome and Mozilla Firefox. But when I load my website on my computer with Internet Explorer 7 it displays this conditional `div`, but it still loads the content below it. Is there a way to stop it loading the content?

Here's my source:

```
<!--[if lte IE 8]>
<div style=' clear: both; text-align:center; position: relative;'>
    <a href="http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/internet-explorer/downloads/ie-9/worldwide-languages"><img src="/protected-wp-content/images/internet-explorer-9-update.png" border="0"  alt="" /></a>
    </div>
<![endif]-->

<!--[if IE 9]>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/html5.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/ie.css" type="text/css" media="screen">
<![endif]-->
```

Comment: `lte IE 8` means "less than equal IE 8" so this seems to work as designed. Can you clarify what the problem is?

Comment: yes it displays the update box. But i'm wondering if there is anyway to stop it displaying the html content which is below this statement and only display it for the other browsers. It would just look more professional

Comment: Ah, the code below wasn't visible in my browser a second ago. You are saying the IE 9 content is visible in IE 7?

Comment: But the IE 9 block doesn't contain anything that would be actually displayed, does it? (Side note: Style sheets are invalid in the document body, they should be in the `head` section)

Comment: basically the pages are designed to work with ie9 and webkit browsers and i dont want them to be displayed by any ie below ie 9 i just want the update div.

Comment: @Pekka let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2193/discussion-between-david-passmore-and-pekka)

Comment: these conditional comments are in the head secition

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, it appears that you want IE 8, and under users to see nothing but the update link?!?!

Leaving off whether that's a good idea, here's how to do it:

```
<!--[if lte IE 8]>
    <div style=" clear: both; text-align:center; position: relative;">
        <a href="http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/internet-explorer/downloads/ie-9/worldwide-languages">
            <img src="/protected-wp-content/images/internet-explorer-9-update.png" border="0"  alt="" />
        </a>
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        document.execCommand("Stop", true, null);
    </script>
<![endif]-->
```

`execCommand("Stop")` halts the page load in IE.  (Doesn't work consistently in other browsers but that's not an issue here. ;)

Comment: Thank you this is what i've been looking for!

Just out of interest why is not a good idea?

Comment: It's not a good idea because you'll be torquing-off some chunk of your customers/clients, needlessly.  For example, on my sites IE<9 users average 20%.  Most operations can't afford to arbitrarily turn away 20% of potential customers! ...  Much better to give them a plain site (Those IE users won't notice a less fancy site. ;)  They WILL notice a site that's militant about blocking their IE.  Some of them may make it a mission to retaliate.)

Comment: well i'm only asking them to update! Only because my css is designed around chrome and Mozilla and most people around 79% of my customers use those browsers and others have been more than happy to update thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

You could enclose the following content in

```
<!--[if gte IE 9]>
   Stuff only Internet Explorer 9 should see..
<![endif]-->
```

Using JavaScript, you can hide the div that loads beneath. Of course, this will break and need modification when Internet Explorer 10 comes out:

```
<div id='divContainingIE9Content'></div>
<script type='text/javascript'>
    if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf("MSIE 9") > 0) {
        document.getElementById("divContainingIE9Content").style.display = 'none';
    }
</script>
```

Comment: I don't know but i'd rather not have it all conditional

Comment: @David Passmore you can do it with javascript to set the CSS property `display: none;` as well. see above.

Comment: You say you want it not to display on IE less than 8. That is the **definition** of being conditional...

Comment: i mean i don't want it all inside conditional tags if i could help it

Answer (score 0):

If your point is to allow "--" within the body of the page, you could enclose it in

```
<!--[if lte IE 8]><div style="display:none"><[endif]-->
...
<!--[if lte IE 8]></div><[endif]-->
```

(But wouldn't work for IE versions so old that they don't do CSS at all (are there any appreciable number of those in the wild?))

Comment: What about starting a HTML comment and closing it below? (to deal with browsers not supporting CSS) - ERR even IE 5 supports CSS.

Comment: The IE conditionals _are_ HTML comments, as far as browsers that don't recognize them are aware.